# Show download bar in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I'm missing the download bar in Chrome. The bar that showed up each time I downloaded a file. (Not CTRL+J).

I got it on my old computer. Have they removed it or are there a configuration option?

Comment: I'm running Chrome 15.0.874.121 (WinXP) and the download bar appears whenever I download a file. I see no option to change this behaviour. Have you tried downloading different file types? I wonder if certain file types are set to 'always open'? What if you right-mouse on a download link and select 'Save link as...'?

Comment: I never see it at my Win7 computer and I've not changed any options

Comment: @HaydnWVN: That is the downloads 'page' (the same as hitting CTRL+J as mentioned in the question). The downloads 'bar' appears at the bottom of the window to show current downloads only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type `chrome://flags` in the URL bar. If a page loads look for 'New Downloads UI'. Disable it if it's enabled.

P.S: These options might not be available in your Chrome version.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is no solution to hide the download bar automatically or display it manually, but google chrome team confirmed [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27797) that they are working on this issue.

Comment: It have never appeared on this computer. I do not want to autohide it, just the default behaviour (i.e. it shows when I click to download a file)

Comment: Have you tried to re-install Chrome/install newer version?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this disappearing download bar when having 99 files downloaded with the same name to the default folder. The file names will have different numbers appended: `file(99).pdf`.

After I deleted/moved these files elsewhere, the download bar re-appeared. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this feature isn't built into Chrome.  I downloaded and extension that shows speed as well as manages the downloads folder.  Here's the link

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en-US

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the downloaded folder was automatically opened on pdf file but it no longer showed on the bar.

I went to Setting -> Advanced -> Download and then remove the automatic open pdf option. Then it's back to normal.